Distribution of $\varepsilon^T P_\Theta \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon, \Theta$ are jointly Gaussian and $P_A = A (A^T A)^{-1} A$ orth. projection
Let $n \geq k$.
Let $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\Theta \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ with
$(\varepsilon, \Theta) \sim \mathcal{MN}((0, \Theta_0), \mathrm{Id}, \Omega)$, where $\mathcal{MN}$ denotes the Matrix normal distribution.
That is, for $\varepsilon = (\varepsilon_1, \ldots, \varepsilon_k)^T $ and $\Theta = (\Theta_1^T, \ldots, \Theta_n^T)^T$, we have $(\varepsilon_i, \Theta_i) \sim \mathcal{N}( (0, \Theta_0), \Omega )$ for $i = 1, \ldots k$ and $i\neq j \Rightarrow (\varepsilon_i, \Theta_i) \perp (\varepsilon_j, \Theta_j)$.
Let $P_A := A (A^T A)^{-1} A^T$ be the projection onto the column space of $A$ and $M_A := \mathrm{Id}_n - P_A$ the projection onto the orthogonal complement.
To show:
The distribution of $\varepsilon^T P_\Theta \varepsilon $ is bounded from below by a $\chi^2(k)$
or
the distribution of $\varepsilon^T M_\Theta \varepsilon$ is bounded from above by a $\chi^2(n - k)$.
Known results:
0.) $\varepsilon^T \varepsilon \sim \chi^2(n)$
This is the definition of the $\chi^2$-distribution.
1.) For any fixed matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ of full rank, we have $\varepsilon^T P_A \varepsilon \sim \chi^2(k)$ and $\varepsilon^T M_A \varepsilon \sim \chi^2(n-k)$.
This is essentially Cochran's theorem and follows from the fact that $P_A$ has eigenvalue 1 with multiplicity $k$ and eigenvalue 0 with multiplicity $n - k$. Thus, $\varepsilon^T P_A \varepsilon = \varepsilon^T Q Q^T \varepsilon$, for some $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ with orthogonal columns such that $Q^T \varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathrm{Id}_k)$. Same argument for $\varepsilon^T M_A \varepsilon$.
2.) If $A$ is random with entries independent of those in $\varepsilon$, then $\varepsilon^T P_A \varepsilon \sim \chi^2(k)$ and $\varepsilon^T M_A \varepsilon \sim \chi^2(n-k)$.
$\varepsilon^T P_A \varepsilon$ is $\chi^2(k)$ conditional for each $A$ and thus also unconditionally. Same for $\varepsilon^T M_A \varepsilon$.
3.) If $\mathbb{E}[\Theta] = \Theta_0 = 0$, then $\varepsilon^T M_\Theta \varepsilon \sim \frac{\mathrm{Var{\varepsilon}}}{\mathrm{Var}(\varepsilon_1) - \mathrm{Cov}(\varepsilon_1, \Omega_1)  \mathrm{Cov}(\Omega_1)^{-1} \mathrm{Cov}(\Omega_1, \varepsilon_1)} \chi^2(n-k) \leq \chi^2(n-k)$.
Write $\varepsilon_i = \Theta_i \beta + \eta$ for $\beta = \mathrm{Cov}(\Theta_1)^{-1} \mathrm{Cov}(\Theta_1, \varepsilon)$ and $\eta \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathrm{Var}(\varepsilon_1) / (\mathrm{Var}(\varepsilon_1) - \mathrm{Cov}(\varepsilon_1, \Omega_1)  \mathrm{Cov}(\Omega_1)^{-1} \mathrm{Cov}(\Omega_1, \varepsilon_1)))$ independent of $\Theta$ (reference).
Then $\varepsilon^T M_\Theta \varepsilon = \eta^T M_\Theta \eta$ and the result follows from 2.).
3.1) If $\mathbb{E}[\Theta] = 0$, then by 3.) $\varepsilon^T P_\Theta \varepsilon \geq \chi^2(k)$.
4.) If $\mathbb{E}[\Theta] = 0$, then for any fixed $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ of norm $ \| v \|_2 = 1$ , we have $v^T P_\Theta v \sim \mathrm{Beta}(k/2, (n-k)/2)$.
Similarly $v^T M_\Theta v \sim \mathrm{Beta}((n-k)/2, k/2)$.
For this let $Q \in O(n)$ be orthonormal ($Q^T Q = \mathrm{Id}_n$). Let $t^2 \sim \chi^2(n)$ and let $Q \mathrm{Unif}(O(n))$, then $t \cdot Qv \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathrm{Id}_n)$ independent of $Q \Theta$. Write
$$
v^T P_\Theta v = \frac{(t \cdot Q v)^T P_{Q \Theta} (t \cdot Q v)}{t^2}.
$$
Let $q_k := (t \cdot Q v)^T P_{Q \Theta} (t \cdot Q v)$ and $q_{n-k} := (t \cdot Q v)^T M_{Q \Theta} (t \cdot Q v)$. These are independent by $P_{Q \Theta} M_{Q \Theta} = 0$ and $\chi^2(k)$ and $\chi^2(n-k)$ by 2.). Finally, $q_k + q_{n-k} = t^2$ and the result follows.
This argument does not work with $\mathbb{E}[\Theta] \neq 0$, as then $Q \Theta$ is not independent of $(t \cdot Qv)$.
Simplification / special case:
Let $\varepsilon_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ be fixed. What can be said about $\varepsilon^T P_{\varepsilon + \varepsilon_0} \varepsilon$ or $\varepsilon^T M_{\varepsilon + \varepsilon_0} \varepsilon = \varepsilon_0^T M_{\varepsilon + \varepsilon_0} \varepsilon_0$?
Related: (1), (2)
